# @Embedded object not instantiated automatically if it has no basic datatype fields

Tags: java, jpa, ebean, embeddable

Fundamental question: Why aren't @Embedded objects always instantiated?

The interesting observation is that Ebean does not instantiate @Embedded objects if those do not contain basic datatypes (int, boolean...) or weren't touched before. Example:

```
@Entity
public class Embedder {
    // getNotAutoInstantiated() will return null if this field was not touched before
    @Embedded
    private NotAutoInstantiated notAutoInstantiated = new NotAutoInstantiated();
    // getAutoInstantiated() will always return an instance!
    @Embedded
    private AutoInstantiated autoInstantiated = new AutoInstantiated();
}

@Embeddable
public class AutoInstantiated {
    // theKey is why this embedded object is always instantiated
    private int theKey; 
    private String field1;      
}

@Embeddable
public class NotAutoInstantiated {
    private String field2;      
}
```

Comment: You may be having a problem with field name collisions between multiple embedded objects. Normally, the JPA provider maps the embedded objects fields to columns in the parent table. If the embedded field names run long, you may end up with truncated field names in the database and therefore collisions in the column names.

Comment: The example may be deceiving. The names are much shorter in my code and they don't start with the same prefix. But even in the example the fields start with "not" and "auto", so truncation would not be a huge issue.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about "field" and "field".

Comment: Oh, thanks. Yes, Ebean does not allow this, and throws an exception before firing up the database. The error is only in the example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think the JPA spec clearly describes what should happen when an `@Embedded` object's properties are *all null*, but at least some implementations treat an object with null properties as a null object, which is what you're seeing.

This seems like a reasonable implementation. Certainly it's been useful in my code (using Hibernate) where if I set an `@Embedded` object to null I want it to remain null when I load a persisted version.

In your example, the `AutoInstantiated` class can never be considered null, since the primitive property `theKey` can never be null.

Comment: Unfortunately, the situation is worse than that. Ebean seems to be not consistent with this behavior. We have a pretty complex data model where AutoInstantiated-like @Embedded fields are really auto instantiated in most of the places. But there is one place where this does not happen. We weren't able to find the peculiarity of that one.
The "leaving it null" approach is not the best for me as it requires  another null checking. This is the worst practice in Java. It could be easily avoided in such cases...

Answer (score 15):

For Hibernate, you might want to check out issue [HHH-7610](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7610).

In particular, since 5.1 there is an experimental feature to change this behavior.  Note that this feature has known issues, and should not be used in production until it is stabilized.  This is detailed in the Javadocs for [org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html)):

```
/**
 * [EXPERIMENTAL] Enable instantiation of composite/embedded objects when all of its attribute values are {@code null}.
 * The default (and historical) behavior is that a {@code null} reference will be used to represent the
 * composite when all of its attributes are {@code null}
 * <p/>
 * This is an experimental feature that has known issues. It should not be used in production
 * until it is stabilized. See Hibernate Jira issue HHH-11936 for details.
 *
 * @since 5.1
 */
String CREATE_EMPTY_COMPOSITES_ENABLED = "hibernate.create_empty_composites.enabled";
```

Set the `hibernate.create_empty_composites.enabled` property to true and voilà!

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. However, the question is related to EBean. Hibernate is probably superior in many aspects, but Ebean fits better with small projects.

Answer (score 4):

I just hit the same issue with Hibernate.
The original question, about the "why" is answered.

But to talk about a solution, I just use a @PostLoad method, so within class *Embedder* something like:

```
@PostLoad
private void initData() {
  if(notAutoInstantiated == null) {
    notAutoInstantiated = new NotAutoInstantiated();
  }
}
```

Update:

**Warning!** The upper code is working, but does have an unexpected side effect! As soon as you load your object with null pointer from the database, it is marked as dirty, because of this post load code!
In my case, this side effects leads to an SQL update command from a thread, which should only load the data and hours of searching this bug!

Answer (score 1):

A similar hack as Martin to avoid NPE when the object is not loaded and avoid side effects.

```
  // workaround as Embeddable objects are not loaded if all their fields are null
  public NotAutoInstantiated getNotAutoInstantiated() {
    if (notAutoInstantiated == null) {
      // WARNING! do not assign this new object to notAutoInstantiated field,
      // this would have side effects as the field is not loaded by Ebean, 
      // Ebean would try to refresh the field in some cases and another NPE would occur:
      // io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultBeanLoader.refreshBeanInternal(DefaultBeanLoader.java:194)
      return new NotAutoInstantiated();
    }
    return notAutoInstantiated;
  }
```